# Как определить первый день нового года?

Tags: php

Как определить через php последний день старого года и 1й день любого нового года?

Comment: 31 декабря и 1 января. Или речь о китайском календаре?

Comment: echo date('w', strtotime('2020-01-01')); - 0-воскресенье и т.д

Comment: @Эникейщик Я надеюсь все-таки, что вопрос о дне недели

Comment: @splash58 без указания года

Comment: И что на самом деле хотите узнать? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37190878/php-datetime-first-day-of-next-year